# Temporarily highlight row of active cell while maintaining original formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to temporarily highlight an entire row of an active cell. I successfully achieved this with the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Cells.ClearFormats
Target.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
End Sub
```

The only issue is using this changes the formatting of the worksheet. Is there something I can add to this formula to tell excel to maintain the original formatting while adding this function to it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Cells.ClearFormats` which removes all formats for all cells, instead just set the `interior.color` property of the `cells` collection to `xlNone`:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Cells.Interior.Color = xlNone
    Target.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow
End Sub
```

This doesn't preserve the original interiot color of the cells in the row that is being deselected though, for that you would have to store the original color for the rows that are gaining the `vbYellow` interior color so that they could be restored on the next selection change.